# Resizable divs in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, lwc-dom

LWC playground

https://app.lwc.studio/edit/CTHEQCGrn18rKmQQ0zs1

I have below HTML

```
    <section class="resizeable-container" >
        <div class="resizeable-item">
            DIV1
        </div>
        <div class="resizer-x" onmousedown={handleOnMouseDown} onmouseup={handleOnMouseUp}></div>
        <div class="resizeable-item">
            DIV2
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.resizeable-container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 80vh;
}

.resizeable-item {
    flex: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.resizer-x {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: hsl(212, 100%, 17%);
    padding: 4px;
}

.resizer-x {
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: col-resize;
}

.resizer-x::before,
.resizer-x::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

Below is the javascript

```
renderedCallback() {
    if (!resizer)
        resizer = this.template.querySelector(".resizer-x")

    //In case mouse up event occurs outside the resizer element
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleOnMouseUp)
}

handleOnMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleOnMouseMove)
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleOnMouseUp)
}

handleOnMouseMove(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    const clientX = event.clientX;
    const deltaX = clientX - (resizer._clientX || clientX);
    resizer._clientX = clientX;
    const { previousElementSibling, nextElementSibling } = resizer
    // LEFT
    if (deltaX < 0) {
        const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(previousElementSibling).width) + deltaX)
        previousElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${clientX < 10 ? 0 : clientX}px`
        nextElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
    }
    // RIGHT
    if (deltaX > 0) {

        const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(nextElementSibling).width) - deltaX)
        nextElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
        previousElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
    }
}


handleOnMouseUp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleOnMouseMove)
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleOnMouseUp)
    delete event._clientX
}
```

The expectation is to move the cursor and resizer-x at the same time but resizer-x moves first and then the cursor moves and mouse up only works if it is coming from the resizer-x anywhere else it is not working. I have added eventListener to document not on a particular object but still removeEventListener to stop handleMouseMove function doesn't stop.

Below is the code pen where it is working as expected but in LWC it doesn't behave in the same manner

https://codepen.io/gs650x/pen/qByPQKP

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `if (deltaX < 0)` block you use `clientX` instead of `width` when setting the style of `previousElementSibling`, that's why resizer-x moves first.

To let the resizer-x bar move even when the mouse is not hover it, I added both `onmouseup` and `onmousemove` to resizeable-container

```html
<template>
    <section class="resizeable-container" onmouseup={handleOnMouseUp} onmousemove={handleOnMouseMove}>
        <div class="resizeable-item blue">
            <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">DIV1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="resizer-x" onmousedown={handleOnMouseDown}></div>
        <div class="resizeable-item bisque">
            <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">DIV2</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

Then in JS I used an instance variable for `resizer` instead of a global one and a flag `canMove`, setted to `true` in the `handleOnMouseDown` method and to `false` in the `handleOnMouseUp`, and then I wrapped the body of `handleOnMouseMove` in an `if (this.canMove)`:

```js
export default class App extends LightningElement {

   resizer;
   canMove = false;

    handleOnMouseDown(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.resizer = event.currentTarget;
        delete this.resizer._clientX
        this.canMove = true;
    }

    handleOnMouseMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.canMove) {
            const clientX = event.clientX;
            const deltaX = clientX - (this.resizer._clientX || clientX);
            this.resizer._clientX = clientX;
            const { previousElementSibling, nextElementSibling } = this.resizer
            // LEFT
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(previousElementSibling).width) + deltaX)
                previousElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
                nextElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
            }
            // RIGHT
            else if (deltaX > 0) {
                const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(nextElementSibling).width) - deltaX)
                nextElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
                previousElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
            }
        }
    }

    handleOnMouseUp(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.canMove = false;
    }

}
```

The CSS is the same, I just added a background-color to the div in this [Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/view/yhLfolD4DUGakKFdwjr0/src/index.stories.js)

Comment: Many thanks for the kind help!