# Can I get the aura component code for resizable div

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

LWC code:

```html
<template>
    <section class="resizeable-container" onmouseup={handleOnMouseUp} onmousemove={handleOnMouseMove}>
        <div class="resizeable-item blue">
            <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">DIV1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="resizer-x" onmousedown={handleOnMouseDown}></div>
        <div class="resizeable-item bisque">
            <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">DIV2</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

JS :

```javascript
export default class App extends LightningElement {

   resizer;
   canMove = false;

    handleOnMouseDown(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.resizer = event.currentTarget;
        delete this.resizer._clientX
        this.canMove = true;
    }

    handleOnMouseMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.canMove) {
            const clientX = event.clientX;
            const deltaX = clientX - (this.resizer._clientX || clientX);
            this.resizer._clientX = clientX;
            const { previousElementSibling, nextElementSibling } = this.resizer
            // LEFT
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(previousElementSibling).width) + deltaX)
                previousElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
                nextElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
            }
            // RIGHT
            else if (deltaX > 0) {
                const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(nextElementSibling).width) - deltaX)
                nextElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
                previousElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
            }
        }
    }

    handleOnMouseUp(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.canMove = false;
    }

}
```

Style:

```css
.resizeable-container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 80vh;
}

.resizeable-item {
    flex: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.resizer-x {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: hsl(212, 100%, 17%);
    padding: 4px;
}

.resizer-x {
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: col-resize;
}

.resizer-x::before,
.resizer-x::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

Link of existing post: [Resizable divs in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/394043/resizable-divs-in-lwc/413053#413053)

Comment: @FelixvanHove Even as a learning exercise, it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This code is trivial to convert to Aura. Here's how to do it.

## Template

There's three changes we need to make the template work. First, we need to convert each click handler from `={method}` to `="{!c.method}"`. Second, we need to add `aura:attribute` elements for each thing LWC stores in `this`. Third, we are going to wrap the entire template inside a div for CSS scoping reasons.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="resizer" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="canMove" type="Boolean" default="{!false}" />
    <div>
        <section class="resizeable-container" onmouseup="{!c.handleOnMouseUp}" onmousemove="{!c.handleOnMouseMove}">
            <div class="resizeable-item blue">
                <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">DIV1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="resizer-x" onmousedown="{!c.handleOnMouseDown}"></div>
            <div class="resizeable-item bisque">
                <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">DIV2</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

## CSS

Next, we just need to prefix every CSS selector with `.THIS`  (note the space, because of how CSS scoping works).

```
.THIS .resizeable-container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 80vh;
}

.THIS .resizeable-item {
    flex: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.THIS .resizer-x {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: hsl(212, 100%, 17%);
    padding: 4px;
}

.THIS .resizer-x {
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: col-resize;
}

.THIS .resizer-x::before,
.THIS .resizer-x::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

## Controller

Finally, we're going to update the controller. We could also move this logic to the helper logic, but I'm going for an easy conversion. First, we change each method from `method(event)` to `method: function(component, event, helper)`, and add a comma after each function body except the last. We replace references to `this` with appropriate calls of `component.get` to read a value and `component.set` to write a value.

Note that in `handleOnMouseDown`, we manipulate the element before storing it in the attribute. This is to avoid any potential problems with Aura and storing attributes, notably Locker Service can do weird things to our objects. You'll see, in particular, that `component.set("v.resizer", resizer);` was added in `handleOnMouseMove` to make sure Aura doesn't lose our `_clientX` value.

The final result is this:

```
({
    handleOnMouseDown: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let resizer = event.currentTarget;
        delete resizer._clientX;
        component.set("v.resizer", resizer);
        component.set("v.canMove", true);
    },

    handleOnMouseMove: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let resizer = component.get("v.resizer");
        if (component.get("v.canMove")) {
            const clientX = event.clientX;
            const deltaX = clientX - (resizer._clientX || clientX);
            resizer._clientX = clientX;
            const { previousElementSibling, nextElementSibling } = resizer
            // LEFT
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(previousElementSibling).width) + deltaX)
                previousElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
                nextElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
            }
            // RIGHT
            else if (deltaX > 0) {
                const width = Math.round(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(nextElementSibling).width) - deltaX)
                nextElementSibling.style.flex = `0 ${width < 10 ? 0 : width}px`
                previousElementSibling.style.flex = "1 0"
            }
            component.set("v.resizer", resizer);
        }
    },
    handleOnMouseUp: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        component.set("v.canMove", false);
    }
})
```